# Android-Dagger2 - Can't get dependencies from Application component into Activity Scope

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am using Dagger 2 for dependency injection, and everything is working just fine if the injection is in the same scope, for example: if the ApplicationComponent is injecting instances in the Application Scope or the ActivityComponent is injecting some instance in the Activity Scope, that's all fine. The problem then happens when I try to make the ActivityComponent depend on the ApplicationComponent and try to get dependencies from there the app does not build at all and I get 3 compiler errors 
 1. Cannot find symbol class DaggerActivityComponent
 2. Cannot find symbol class DaggerApplicationCom
 3. cannot access Nullable.
I have searched for this like everywhere but nothing seems to solve the problem.

here is the ApplicationComponent:

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
void inject(MyApplication application);
}
```

Here is the ActivityComponent:

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(modules = {ActivityModule.class}, dependencies =   ApplicationComponent.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {

void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

Here is the ApplicationModule:

```
@Module
```

public class ApplicationModule {

```
@Provides
public Retrofit retrofit(GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
            .build();
}

@Provides
public Gson gson() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    return gsonBuilder.create();
}


@Provides
public GsonConverterFactory gsonConverterFactory(Gson gson) {
    return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson);
}
}
```

Here is the ActivityModule

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {

}
```

Here is the Application Class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

ApplicationComponent component;

@Inject
Retrofit retrofit;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule())
            .build();
    component.inject(this);
}

public  ApplicationComponent component() {
    return component;
}
}
```

And finally the Activity:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

ApplicationComponent component;

@Inject
Retrofit retrofit;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule())
            .build();
    component.inject(this);
}

public  ApplicationComponent component() {
    return component;
}
}
```

Please help, and thank u.

Comment: the application does not crash cuz we don't get to this level, it does not even build successfully.

Comment: You've pasted your MyApplication twice without showing us MyActivity. My hunch is that your "Cannot access Nullable" is actually the problem: If Dagger can't compile your MyActivity class, it won't generate its implementations at DaggerApplicationComponent or DaggerActivityComponent, so your app won't work even though Dagger is configured correctly. If that's not enough, please post the exact compiler error message and the text of MyActivity.

Comment: https://github.com/cppgarbagecollector/Dagger2Example
here is a side of what I am experiencing, Thank u so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, all what u need to do is just add a getter method for the dependencies that need to be injected by the ApplicationComponent in the ApplicationComponent interface like that.

for example if u need Retrofit such as in your case here u normally define the @Provides method in the ApplicationModule and add

```
Retrofit getRetrofit();
```

in the ApplicationComponent.

I hope that helps